# Getting 'ERR EXEC without MULTI' when using RedisIO from Apache Beam API.

Tags: redis, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm reading data from BigQuery and writing to Redis using RedisIO from Apache Beam API. Below is the code snippet.

```
pipeline.apply("Read Data From BigQuery",
        BigQueryIO.readTableRows().withoutValidation()
            .fromQuery(""))
    .apply("Convert Table rows into Redis Entity",
        ParDo.of(new RedisEntity()))
    .apply("Write to Redis",
        RedisIO.write().withEndpoint("localhost", 6379));
```

When trying to execute the code, I get 2,000 records written in redis and after that getting the below error.

> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: EXEC without MULTI
>       at redis.clients.jedis.Pipeline.exec(Pipeline.java:139)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.redis.RedisIO$Write$WriteFn.processElement(RedisIO.java:419)

Kindly advice if I'm missing something or if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Seem like a bug in RedisIO, I have submitted an issue to Beam, and have done a pull request to fix it. See if I guess it correctly. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5714

Answer (score 2):

Seem like a bug in RedisIO, I have submitted an issue to Beam, and have done a pull request to fix it. See if I guess it correctly. issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5714